# CMAKE for /DEF and /NODEFAULTLIB

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, linker-flags

How do I add linker-flags "DEF" and "NODEFAULTLIB" to vs2012 project via CMAKE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can append them to [`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS):

```
if(MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
      "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /DEF:my_defs.def /NODEFAULTLIB")
endif()
```

Comment: SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(name PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -DEF:"ExportedFunctions.def" -NODEFAULTLIB:"mfc110d" ) this does not work, i have "module definition file", but no "ignore specific default library"..

Comment: You should be able to do `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(name PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/DEF:\"ExportedFunctions.def\" /NODEFAULTLIB:\"mfc110d\"")`

Comment: Or to CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS, or to CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS ... oh, no, whatever!

Comment: what mean: /DEF:my_defs.def ?

Comment: make my da...night. Thank you !

Comment: @Fraser: Do you really need the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

The general way is to add linker flags to `CMAKE_xxx_LINKER_FLAGS`, yes. However in case of `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` and `/DEF:` parameter, there is a special case that made me run into trouble.

If you already use `CMAKE_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` (`CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS`) then the `/DEF:` parameter will not appear in the linking command, even if you specified it in `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`.

This is because MSVC linker accepts only one `/DEF:` parameter, and CMake does not want to override the existing one: `/DEF:<build_path>/exports.def` (which is added due to `CMAKE_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS`) with the one which you specify in the `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`.

You can use also `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`. It adds arbitrary linker flags without checking them, but it adds them into the middle of the linking command before the `/DEF:<build_path>/exports.def` so that the latter won't get overridden.

The full discussion of this case here: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2019-November/031274.html.